# UIPanGestureReconizer for Volume Control

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, volume, pan

I'm working on an app with gesture recognizers. I'm stuck on trying to get this to work. I am trying to get a UIPanGestureReconizer to detect when the user slides the finger up or down on the UIImageView and adjust a UISlider which would adjust the volume. I have been stuck on this for a few days. Read docs and everything, I couldn't find anything on what I'm trying to do. Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit, and maybe post code? "It doesn't work" is not very helpful. What doesn't work - the volume setting or the gesture recognizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `translationInView:` method to get the translation of the touch. You can check the direction of the translation based on this and accordingly alter the slider value. If you don't want to handle the direction detection, you can look at swipes but you will probably lose the precision that you are expecting of a translation if any.

And one more thing, did you set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`. It is set to `NO` by default for image views.

Comment: Going to give that a try tonight when I get home. I'll let you know how it all goes.